# Getting ISO8601 from JodaTime with milliseconds

Tags: java, date, timezone, jodatime, iso8601

I want to convert my date `"2013-03-04T23:00:00"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` but I keep getting `"2013-03-04'T'23:00:00.000+0000"`. Any help?

item.getEnd() is a XMLGregorianCalendar by the way.

```
Calendar calendar  = item.getEnd().toGregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date = calendar.getTime();
DateTime iso8601 = new DateTime(calendar);

iso8601.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: What is the problem? That millis is `000`?

Comment: The ISO8601 format doesn't require any particular precision.  Omitting decimals, or even completely omitting the seconds field, are both completely valid.

Comment: I agree but the API I'm working against seems to only like that format.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what API is it that requires the specific precision?  I recall reading a post a while back about some web browser that required zero or three decimal places of precision, but failed on two.  I can't find that post now... Is it a JavaScript API you are feeding it to? or something else?

Comment: I believe it's a java backend cant be for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `ISODateTimeFormat` class that is built in to JodaTime.  The example in [the documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) is:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```